# ContextBoundObject with Async/Await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, aop, async-await

I have a system which uses AOP with ContextBoundObject.

This is used to intercept a method call and perform certain operations before and after the function. It all works fine until I make the 'function to be intercepted' async.

I understand that the C# compiler rewrites async methods into a state machine, which returns control to the sink as soon as 'await' is reached
So it continues into the interception and executes the code which is meant to be executed only after the Method.

I can see there is an "AsyncProcessMessage" in IMessageSink, but I can't find a way to invoke it, and I am not sure if it will work in the async/await scenario.

Is there a way to make Async/Await work with the ContextBoundObject? Is using another Aspect Oriented Programming approach the only option here?

The code sample below has the method to be intercepted decorated with the 'Audit' attribute and placed in the AuditFacade which is a ContextBoundObject. The SyncProcessMessage method in the AuditSink has the logic to be executed before and after the method.

```
 [AuditBoundary]
public class AuditFacade : ContextBoundObject
{
    [Audit]
    public ResponseObject DoSomthing()
    {
        //Do something
        return new ResponseObject();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Async Method to be intercepted
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Audit]
    public async Task<ResponseObject> DoSomthingAysnc()
    {
        //Do something Async
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        return new ResponseObject();
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuditAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AuditBoundaryAttribute : ContextAttribute
{
    public AuditBoundaryAttribute()
        : base("AuditBoundary" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    {
    }
    public override void GetPropertiesForNewContext(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
    {
        ctorMsg.ContextProperties.Add(new AuditProperty());
    }
}

public class AuditProperty : IContextProperty, IContributeObjectSink
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "AuditProperty"; }
    }

    public bool IsNewContextOK(Context newCtx)
    {
        var p = newCtx.GetProperty("AuditProperty") as AuditProperty;

        if (p == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public void Freeze(Context newContext)
    {
    }

    public IMessageSink GetObjectSink(MarshalByRefObject obj, IMessageSink nextSink)
    {
        return new AuditSink(nextSink);
    }

}

public class AuditSink : IMessageSink
{
    private IMessageSink nextSink;

    public AuditSink(IMessageSink nextSink)
    {
        this.nextSink = nextSink;
    }

    public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
    {
        var message = msg as IMethodCallMessage;

        IMethodReturnMessage returnMessage = null;
        ResponseObject response;

        //Some Pre Processing happens here
        var newMessage = new MethodCallMessageWrapper(message);

        //Invoke the Method to be Audited
        returnMessage = nextSink.SyncProcessMessage(newMessage) as IMethodReturnMessage;
        response = returnMessage.ReturnValue as ResponseObject;

        //Some Post Processing happens here with the "response"
        return returnMessage;
    }

    public IMessageSink NextSink
    {
        get { return this.nextSink; }
    }
    public IMessageCtrl AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
    {
        return nextSink.AsyncProcessMessage(msg, replySink);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about `ContextBoundObject`, but I think that `AsyncProcessMessage()` has nothing to do with `async`-`await` and that the following should work using the normal `SyncProcessMessage()`:

1. Do your preprocessing step.
2. Invoke the async method.
3. Add your postprocessing step as a continuation to the returned `Task`, using `ContinueWith()` or `await`.
4. Return the continuation `Task` to the caller.

If you're okay with your postprocessing executing on the thread pool, then `ContinueWith()` is probably simpler. If you need the postprocessing to execute on the original context, use `await`.

The `await` version could look like this:

```
var responseTask = (Task<ResponseObject>)returnMessage.ReturnValue;

Func<Task<ResponseObject>> postProcessTaskFunc = async () =>
{
    var response = await responseTask;
    // Some Post Processing happens here with the "response"
    return response;
}

return new ReturnMessage(postProcessTaskFunc(), …);
```